# NativeScript RadDataForm Angular CSS styling ignored when defining form groups

Tags: ios, css, angular, nativescript, styling

CSS is ignored when grouping RadDataForm form fields with TKPropertyGroup elements.

I'm using this simple CSS to try to make iOS form fields appear the same as Android form fields, with the label on top instead of on the left:

```
DataFormEditorLabel {
    position: top;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

This works fine on an ungrouped form, but when grouping fields with TKPropertyGroup elements, the CSS is ignored.

Form XML, without the surrounding GridLayout, is:

```
<RadDataForm row="2" [source]="address">
    <TKPropertyGroup tkDataFormGroups collapsible="true" name="Edit this address" collapsed="true">
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="address" hintText="address" index="0">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="address2" index="1">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="city" index="2">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="state" index="3">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="postcode" index="4">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="country" index="5">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text"></TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
    </TKPropertyGroup>
</RadDataForm>
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem, or am I missing something that is needed to make it work?

Comment: Looks like a bug with plugin itself, you might want to raise an issue in [feedback repo](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback).

Comment: Thanks @Manoj, I wasn't aware of the feedback repo.  I have a workaround now, but will raise an issue there.

Comment: Raised https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/1321

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround to CSS not working for iOS, I added a TKPropertyEditorStyle child to achieve what I wanted:

```
<RadDataForm row="2" [source]="address">
    <TKPropertyGroup tkDataFormGroups collapsible="true" name="Edit this address" collapsed="false" hidden="false">
        <TKEntityProperty tkPropertyGroupProperties name="address" hintText="address" index="0">
            <TKPropertyEditor tkEntityPropertyEditor type="Text">
                <TKPropertyEditorStyle tkPropertyEditorStyle labelPosition="Top"></TKPropertyEditorStyle>
            </TKPropertyEditor>
        </TKEntityProperty>
...
```

Information which led me to this workaround is at https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ng-components/ng-DataForm/dataform-styling under "Styling Editors".